# Is ActiveNetworkInfo the right NetworkInfo?

Tags: android, android-broadcast, connectivity

I have been working on a softphone application that is having issues with re-registering to a SIP Server  when it is switching connections. I have a BroadcastReciever that handle CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE but I am having issue with the logic in between.

My code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    debugIntent(intent);
    SipManager sipManager = (SipManager) context.getApplicationContext();
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(activeNetwork != null){
        boolean isActiveConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();

        LogText.appendLog(TAG + "  Type: " + activeNetwork.getTypeName() + " isActiveConnected: " + isActiveConnected);

        if(isActiveConnected){
            sipManager.reRegister;
        }
        else {
            sipManager.lostConnectionUpdate();
        }
    }
    else {
        sipManager.lostConnectionUpdate();
    }
}

private void debugIntent(Intent intent) {
    LogText.appendLog(TAG + " action: " + intent.getAction());
    LogText.appendLog(TAG + " component: " + intent.getComponent());
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
       for (String key: extras.keySet()) {
          LogText.appendLog(TAG + " key [" + key + "]: " +extras.get(key)); 
       }
    }
    else {
       LogText.appendLog(TAG + "no extras");
    }
 }
```

Questions:

What NetworkInfo should I use?

Is it better to get my NetworkInfo from the context or the intent?

I look at my logs and see that when my debugIntent method says I am DISCONNECTED my isActiveConnected boolean returns true anyway.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this static method to check if the device has connectivity or not. It works pretty good.

```
public static boolean hasConnectivity(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    final ConnectivityManager mConnMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = null;
    try {
        info = ConnectivityManagerCompat.getNetworkInfoFromBroadcast(mConnMan, intent);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        info = mConnMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }
    return info != null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

You can change the `info.isConnectedOrConnecting()` to `info.isConnected()` if you want.

In your broadcast receiver you can call:

```
boolean connected = hasConnectivity(context, intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do, and please bear in mind that it doesn't matter what approach you use, as long as you get your code working properly.

The code that I show you here has comments to explain what could be done.

```
public class ConnectionBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")) {


            //An instance of connectivity manager
            ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            //In order to access methods created in the MainActivity from this broadcast
            MainActivity main = (MainActivity)context;


            //Get wifi and mobile connections
            NetworkInfo wifi = conn.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            NetworkInfo mobile = conn
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);



            if (wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isConnected()) {

                //When the device is connected, connect or re-connect to the SIP server
                //Example:
                main.connectToSip()


            } else {

                //The device is not connected, disconnected from the sip server in order
                //to re-register when the device gets connected again
                main.disconnectSip();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

If you have any more questions, you can let me know as I just spend about 5 months working on a similar project.

Comment: Am I ok to reference the application class the way I did? I am checking your code now

Comment: You can you do that, I find out that when working with SIP stuff you might need to use some threading.

Comment: You might want to reference the application class from the main class instead, as a public static so you can access it in the broadcast

Comment: What is the reasoning to go through my MainActivity instead of my application class? An explanation would be helpful

Comment: MainActivity is your application class, it can be called anything but i use MainActivity because I don't know the name of your application class, it can be MyApplication or anything else.

Comment: Oh ok. I have in my code, displayed above, it is called sip manager. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66778/discussion-between-azael-and-bigt).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve your problem with my code. Anyone can check in the Github [Android Network Connection](https://github.com/subhanshuja/AndroidNetworkConnection/tree/develop) i used by kotlin code. Even though, it is deprecated but is worked alike magic